# Eloquent/query relationship bug?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a `Customer` model which hasMany `CustomerContactInfo` and hasMany `CustomerBillingInfo` relationships.

In the controller `update` I get a payload and it contains data for all the three models and I seperate them in the controller. When I want to update the models I have:

```
($customer = Customer::find($request->route('id')))->update($customerData);
$customer->billing_info->first()->update($customerBillingInfo);
$customer->contact_info->first()->update($customerContactInfo);
```

Before you asking why I have hasMany relationship when I only using the first one is because in the first version of my app will only has one billing info and contact info. In the future it will contains many so I'm halfly preparing for that event.

I wrote a test for this route and the test gave back 200. Hovewer when I try on the frontend it give me an SQL error and laravel inject `where 'id' is null` in the update query but *only* for the *contact_info upate query*. I know the solution for my problem is that I did not have a primary key before, because right know the `customer_billing_infos` and `customer_contact_infos` have `customer_id` and no `id` column. And I can solve my problem if I insert `protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';` line in the CustomerContactInfo model (and also the billing info). I know I should have and I will insert id column for all the contact info and billing info records, but know what I don't understand is the source of the problems:

- How is the frontend throwed and error while test is not? I logged all the data I get in the controller to compare what I get from both. The datas are identical. Same variable names and variable count.
- How is the billing info update did not throw and error while it has the same exact relationship as contact info? It has the same belongsTo and hasMany relationship in the models and it does not have any `id` column either. I tried to change the update order in the controller, even I changed the relationships order in the models.

Is this a bug or laravel cache something that I don't know or what is happening?
(using Laravel 9)

Comment: How did you conduct the test? How `$customerBillingInfo` and `$customerContactInfo` data structures look like?

Comment: Created them with factory CustomerBillingInfo::factory()->for($customer)->create() and same as contact info and with ->toArray() I merged all the customer, customerBillingInfo and customerContactInfo to a big array and $this->put('/..', bigArray). Both customerBillingInfo and customerContactInfo schema has customer_id, fields and timestamps. Factory correctly creates the data same as the frontend payload